# hbase execute batch statement

Tags: database, lucene, hbase

I am using lucene 3.0.1 to index a column in hbase. After making query in lucene I am getting a array of keys (which is of same format I have key in hbase) in java, now for all of these keys I want to make query to hbase and get corresponding rows from database. I am not able to find IN operator in hbase documentation, other option is I loop over set of keys and make query to hbase but in this case I will be making lot of hbase database calls. Is there any other option any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You could turn to [get a list](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTable.html#get%28java.util.List%29). Each Get in the list is created using a key you got after querying lucene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The get method of the HTable class can accept a list of GET objects and fetch them all as batch [see the documentation](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTable.html#get%28java.util.List%29)

You essentially need to do something like

```
 List<Get> rowsToGet= new ArrayList<Get>();
 for (String id:resultsFromLucene)
       rowsToGet.add(new Get(Bytes.toBytes(id)));  
 Result[] results = htable.get(rowsToGet);
```